# Is it possible to divide data into separate principal components?

Tags: pca

My question is really basic, if I have used PCA on some data to get it into lower dimension, is it possible do group data into each separate principal component? E.g. this data "belongs" in PC1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you're thinking of PCA sideways. PCA, like many other dimension-reduction methods, is a means for organizing the *variables*, not the *cases*. You can use PCA (or, e.g., factor analysis) to assign variables to groups, not cases to groups. If you want to group cases, you want some kind of [cluster analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis), such as K-means.

Comment: Thank you for the clear answer! How would you go about in assigning the variables in groups in PCA/Factor analysis?

Comment: @joddm That's a potentially complex topic, especially in the case of factor analysis. I'm not going to attempt to answer it as a comment on another question.